# Firestore: Is it possible to filter multiple fields in a collection using whereArrayContains?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an application for pet services where users could choose five conditions to their searches. They are required to choose the type of service they want, the type of pets, number of pets, the region and subregion that they want. They will make their selection through spinners. The result will display the lists of users who provide the services based on their filter.

I have learnt that firestore only allows using whereArrayContains once in a query. How can combine all these queries to filter each related field in the collections? Is it possible to use AND operator?

This was my code.

```
Query query = collectionReference.whereArrayContains("pet", pettype)
.whereArrayContains("service", "Pet Sitting")
.whereArrayContains("petnum", petnumber)
.whereArrayContains("region", reg)
.whereArrayContains("subregion", subreg);
```

I tried merging queries into task and in the onsuccesslistener, I created a toast message to see if it works. It did work but I can't figure out how to place recyclerview into the onsuccesslistener without an error.

```
    private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        Query query = collectionReference.whereArrayContains("pet", pettype);
        Query query2 = collectionReference.whereArrayContains("service", "Pet Sitting");
        Query query3 = collectionReference.whereArrayContains("petnum", petnumber);
        Query query4 = collectionReference.whereArrayContains("region", reg);
        Query query5 = collectionReference.whereArrayContains("subregion", subreg);

        Task task = query.get();
        Task task2 = query2.get();
        Task task3 = query3.get();
        Task task4 = query4.get();
        Task task5 = query5.get();

        Task<List<QuerySnapshot>> combinedtask = Tasks.whenAllSuccess(task, task2, task3, task4, task5);
        combinedtask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<QuerySnapshot>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshots) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Value passed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        //only manages to display one query
       FirestoreRecyclerOptions<model> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<model>().setQuery(query, model.class).build();
        adapter = new myadapter(options);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have already noted and as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership): "You can use at most one `array-contains` clause per query."

**However**, in your case, you may be able to use the following approach:

For a given document, for each of the 5 search criteria, for each possible value for the criteria, add, in the document, **a new field** of type boolean which name is composed by the concatenation of the criteria and the value, and which value is `true`.

For example, let's take two criteria: *service* and *region*.

If your array `service` has two elements: `service1` and `service2` you create two fields `service_service1` and `service_service2` in the document, with a value of true.

If your array `region` has three elements: `r1`, `r2` and `r3` you create three fields `region_r1`, `region_r2` and `region_r3` with a value of true.

Then, you can query as follows:

```
  db.collection('test')
    .where('region_r1', '==', true)
    .where('service_service2', '==', true)
    .get()
    .then(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
      });
    });
```

Note that this approach will not work if you want to combine the equality operators with some inequality operators (<, <=, >, and !=) because you would need to create some [composite indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing).

Comment: I got the 'cannot resolve method 'where' in collectionReference' warning..

Comment: Can you show the exact code generating the error? Please edit your question and add it at the bottom.

Comment: Wait, but do i add the additional field within the array or outside of the array? Because i might need to change the code during adding data to database too.

Comment: "Wait, but do i add the additional field within the array or outside of the array?" => outside the array! :-) They are additional fields. You can do that through the front-end code when you add a new document to the database, or you could use a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) that updates the document when created or modified, reading the arrays and creating/adapting the extra fields.

Comment: I see.. i will give it a try later. But what do you think about combine queries into tasks?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by «combine query into tasks»?

Comment: I mean merging queries. I have updated my question..